# Paginate in server side WebApi Rest .NetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, single-page-application, ef-core-2.0, webapi

How to paginate in server side web api .net core 2.2+ using EF Core and Angular? Because before i was using paginated in frontend, but it is not recommended for performance reasons.

Comment: Hi Anderson, please show us what you have tried first and then ask if you get stuck on an issue. The question so far doesn't show that you've made any attempt.

Comment: @Anderson welcome to SO! Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - i am afraid your question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paginate in the backend using EF you can take advantage of Skip and Take methods. It depends of several things but supposing you can "freeze" or have a stable group of ordered records in the database you can do something like:

```
int pageSize=20;
int pageNumber=3;
IQueryable<MyEntity> entities = context.MyEntity.AsNoTracking()
                                                .FromSql(query, parameters);
entities.OrderBy(e => e.Id);
entities = entities.Skip(pageSize*(pageNumber)).Take(pageSize);
```

Keep in mind this is not always possible depending of new and delete records or change in the order by field. But the good news is that this is multi-database supported.